# Prevent a serialized struct in Rust from being deserialized into a different one

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I want to prevent that data with the same attribute names, but different semantics cannot be accidentally loaded into one-another. For example:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
struct RubyVersionV1 {
    // Records explicit or default version we want to install
    version: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
struct RubyVersionV2 {
    // Programmer realized that there was ambiguity in their prior storage schema
    //
    // They want to decouple an explicit version, from the default case.
    // To make this change they switch to using an Option stores None
    // when a default is used, and Some when an explicit version is used.
    version: Option<String>,
}

// Both use a trait to deliver the information the program needs
trait RubyVersion {
    fn version_to_install(&self) -> String;
}

impl RubyVersion for RubyVersionV1 {
    fn version_to_install(&self) -> String {
        self.version.clone()
    }
}

const DEFAULT_VERSION: &str = "3.2.2";

impl RubyVersion for RubyVersionV2 {
    fn version_to_install(&self) -> String {
        self.version
            .clone()
            .unwrap_or_else(|| DEFAULT_VERSION.to_string())
    }
}
```

Runnable example:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94308306cf81e0fcaff06fb3a2457a6b

In this code, data serialized to disk from `RubyVersionV1` could be accidentally deserialized as `RubyVersionV2`.

This is a trivial example that is trying to demonstrate the more complicated domain that I'm working on (PR https://github.com/heroku/buildpacks-ruby/pull/246). If I can guarantee that V1 can NEVER be deserialized to V2 (rather than requiring the programmer to be careful) then my users' lives will be much easier.

Comment: I tried using the "tag" attribute on serde, but found that you cannot deserialize a struct that's been serialized using that feature. I opened an issue https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/2666

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by adding a void field to each struct to act as a version marker:

```
use serde::{ Serialize, Deserialize };

#[derive (Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
struct V1 {
    text: String,
    version1: (),
}

#[derive (Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
struct V2 {
    text: Option<String>,
    version2: (),
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = V1::default();
    let s1 = serde_json::to_string (&v1).unwrap();
    let v2: Result<V2, _> = serde_json::from_str (&s1);
    println!("{v1:?} -> {s1} -> {v2:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f09dcd7a7db4e63ba0ca5d0a563e9864)